# How to test async useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

How to test async `useEffect` with `react-testing-libs` ?

i have:

```js
// in other file
const getData = () => {
  return new Promsise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve([1, 2, 3]), 5000));
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await getData();
      setData(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return <div>{data.map(item => <span>{item}</span>)}</div>
};
```

How test this component?

my test now:

```js
it('MyComponent test', async () => {
  await act( async () => {
    render(<MyComponent/>, container);
  });

  expect(container.innerHTML).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

But act, render doesn't wait for useEffect().

Why ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

react-testing-library has a clean solution for this. You can wait for the element to appear in the DOM, which means your async `useEffect` ran its course.

It's called [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/) and it will wait for an assertion to complete before continuing the code. You can use the other utilities like `getByText` to `expect`

```
it('MyComponent test', async () => {
  await act( async () => {
    render(<MyComponent/>, container);
  });

  await waitFor(() => {
    // I'd look for a real text here that is renderer when the data loads
    expect(container.queryElement('span')).toBeDefined();
  })

  expect(container.innerHTML).toMatchSnapshot();

});
```

Comment: It was the `await act(async () => {})` that I was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `await act` does anything here as promises run in `useEffect` can't be awaited since they are floating.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```js
test('My Test', async () => {
  const queries = render(<MyComponent/>, container);

  expect(await queries.findByText((content, element) => element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span')).toBeInTheDocument();

  expect(container.innerHTML).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

I couldn't test it, so please let me know if it works.

I read this [comment](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/667#issuecomment-628273598) on a `react-testing-library` issue and then I took a look into [this piece of documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#findby). It seems that there are many ways of customizing this test behavior.

Comment: render returns void

Comment: @Alex4answer it is strange, not according to [this](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#findby).

Comment: The code doesn't say which `render` function is being used, because there's no `import` statement.