# How to use Jest to check if async loaded content is rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that renders a list of data, given by a hook. My hook returns some data on the component mount so the component always has some items to render.

MyList component:

```
function MyList() {
  let {data} = useLoadData()
  return (
      <ul>
        {data.map(i => <li key={i}>{i}</li>)}
      </ul>
  )
}
```

Data loader hook:

```
function useLoadData() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const fetchData = useCallback((params) => {
    fetch("url")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => setData(res))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return {data, fetchData}
}
```

My test is something like this but It doesn't pass.
MyList.test.js

```
test('check if list contains item1', async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    render(<MyList/>)
  });

  await waitFor(() => {
    // I'd look for a real text here that is renderer when the data loads
    expect(screen.getByText('item1')).toBeInTheDocument();
  })

  const item1 = screen.getByText("item1");
  expect(item1).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

I want to use jest to check if the initial data was rendered or not, is there any way to do it?

I use ReactTestingLibrary.

Comment: what library do you use? Enzyme, ReactTestingLibrary, something else? generally speaking there are the same steps 1) mock external data source 2) render component 3) wait till mocked Promise to be fullfilled 4) check something new has been rendered. For Enzyme 3+4 will be more complex, while for RTL 3+4 are way easier.

Comment: @skyboyer I use ReactTestingLibrary.

Comment: then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635054/how-to-test-async-useeffect

Comment: separately you will need to mock `fetch` response, but there are a tons of examples https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjestjs%5D+mock+fetch so probably you already dealt with this part

Comment: @skyboyer thank you for your comments. But I render new items according to the data the hook returns. how should I implement this in my test? I'm just confused.

Comment: how does your test look currently? I mean, I think that you already have 1) mock external source(`fetch`) 2) render element; add it to the question so it would be easier to answer with specific code instead of talking "in general"

Comment: @skyboyer I updated the question by adding my current test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241330/discussion-between-skyboyer-and-behnam-azimi).

Answer (score 0):

make an async jest test to hold the test

```
 it("it should test", async () => {
      const wrapper = mount(<Component />)
      await new Promise(function (res) {
        setTimeout(()=> res("done"),4000)
      })
        expect(wrapper)...   
  });
```

Comment: RTL definitely can wait for element to appear so we would not need that hack with `Promise` as Enzyme requires