# How to wait for state update before testing react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

so I have this react component that calls out to an API and then updates the state and just prints out that data in a div. I've not done much in terms of testing React components so far so I'm quite unsure on what to do.

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  apiOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
    }
  };

  lastFilters = null

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      games: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchGames([]).then(result => this.setState({
      games: result
    }))
  }

  fetchGames(filters) {
    return fetch(`https://${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/games`, this.apiOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        return response
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }

  render() {
    return <div data-testid="json">{JSON.stringify(this.state.games)}</div>
  }
}
```

I've tried using `waitFor` and `findByTestId` and then checking the content of the div but nothing has worked. Does anyone know how I'd do this? I've also tried using `msw` to mock the result of the API call but that didn't work either.

Test code:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';


test('renders text', () => {
  render(<App />);

  expect(screen.getByTestId('json')).toBe([])
});
```

Comment: Where is the test code?

Comment: @fasaas I've just updated with some very basic one after everything didn't work but hopefully you get the idea of what I was trying to do.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635054/how-to-test-async-useeffect?

Comment: @fasaas as its a class component I can't use `useEffect`? that's handled by `componentDidMount`? But in that answer on there I'm not sure where the `container` variable comes from?

Comment: useEffect and componentDidMount are actually the same in this case, it's an abstraction that achieves the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

- mock the fetch method
- wait until it is called
- wait until your data is rendered

```js
import { render, waitFor, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import YourComponent from '../YourComponent'

it('should work', async () => {
  const mockedFetch = jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockResolvedValue({ json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ some: 'object' }) })
  render(<YourComponent />)

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(mockedFetch).toHaveBeenCalled()
  });
  
  await waitFor(() => {
    const element = screen.queryByText(JSON.stringify({ some: 'object' }));
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
  })
});
```