# How do I test a React Native Context that has an a sync call in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, testing-library

There are other questions similar but this is specific to React Native and I have a React Context which has a provider and the provider has a `useEffect` hook that calls an async function that would update the state.

The actual async operation I have mocked to return a resolved promise.

Initially I did this to make sure the initial states are okay

```
const { getByTestId} = render(<FontProvider><My Component /></FontProvider>);
expect(getByTestId(...
```

The default state works as expected but when I want the next state after the useEffect it does not work. Obviously because I didn't wrap in `act`.

However, I am unable to [wrap around `act` since it is a `render` call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65635636/242042). At least not in `@testing-library/react-native`  as it shows

> Can't access .root on unmounted test renderer

Is there something else I may be missing?

I'm not using `setTimeout` so `jest.runAllTimers();` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was close with the `jest.runAllTimers()`.  There's another method `jest.runAllTicks()` but still requires fake timers.

```
beforeEach(() => { jest.useFakeTimers(); });

it("...", () => {
  ...
  const { getByTestId } = 
    render((<FontsProvider fontModules={[mockFont]}>
      <MyComponent /></FontsProvider>);

  // runs the useEffects no need for async/await
  act(() => { jest.runAllTicks() })

  expect(getByTestId("blah").props.style).toStrictEqual(
    { fontFamily: "IBMPlexSans_300Light" });
);

afterEach(() => { jest.useRealTimers(); });
```